# EPS2PDF conversion not working in latex

Tags: floats, kile, epstopdf, includegraphics

I am writing a research paper in latex template which has some figures in `EPS` format. While compiling the template I see a blank box instead of figure I'm not getting why it's happening

I have used

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

in the preamble but still, it doesn't work. Any guess why it's happening.

**Code**

```
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figs/Fig1}
\caption{Experiment results for D=250}
\label{Figure:exp_250}
\end{figure*}
```

**Output**

[image]

I am using `Kile` in `Ubuntu`.

Comment: what you show is the output from `[draft]` mode.  Note you should not have to use `epstopdf` package these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not enabled `\write18` which allows LaTeX to call external programs. 
From the documentation:

> The feature \write18 must be enabled. This allows the running of
>   external programs during TEX’s compile run. Keep in mind that this is
>   a security risk. The feature is an addition to \TeX. MikTEX, teTEX,
>   TEX Live support it. In Web2C based TEX distributions (teTEX, TEX
>   Live) it can be enabled in the configuration file texmf.cnf:
>   shell_escape = 1

Simply call e.g. pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` should do the trick. In Kile you need to edit the command via Settings => Configure Kile => Build

Comment: eps to pdf conversion is allowed without `shell-escape` these days (so long as the epstopdf package isn't loaded and the core `graphics` package code is used (which uses a restricted version of epstopdf allowed in that context)

Comment: Hello @UweZiegenhagen, I have changed the command in `Settings` => `Configure Kile` => `Build` from `PDFLaTeX`+`ViewPDF` to `LaTeX` + `DVItoPDF` + `ViewPDF`. Now I can see the figure but Caption is appearing at left of the figure instead of the bottom.
https://s33.postimg.cc/ksdd1vn33/plot2.png

Comment: What happens if you just use the figure, not figure* environment? AFAIK is is used in two-column typesetting.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Problem still persists. The figure is wide I need to show it in 2 columns.

Comment: Are you using the draft option for your documentclass?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Hello, my document class is `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`

Comment: Without a real minimal example we can't help.